# Using Weierstrass’s Factorization Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, taylor-series, cv.complex-variables

I am trying to factorize $\sin(x)\over x$ which by [Taylor series expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_theorem) and using the roots is $$a \cdot \left(1 - \frac{x}{\pi} \right) \left(1 + \frac{x}{\pi} \right) \left(1 -  \frac{x}{2\pi} \right) \left(1 + \frac{x}{2\pi} \right) \left(1 - \frac{x}{3\pi} \right) \left(1 + \frac{x}{3\pi} \right) \cdots$$

Now I was told that this nasty factor $a$ conveniently becomes $1$ due to [Weierstrass’s Factorization Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) which is a transcendental generalization of the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

**My question**
Could you please show me how $a$ is being neutralized using this theorem? Or don't you even need this theorem to do so?

Comment: Look at the limit of both sides as x tends to 0?

Comment: By the way, you might be interested to know that this is how Euler cracked the [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler_attacks_the_problem)

Comment: Thank you, yes - ironically this was the place I was coming from - have a look at the discussion page below ;-) But now everything is clear and I clarified the Wikipedia article with some additional comments.

Comment: But note that you should consider products of $\exp\left(\frac{x}{\pi n}\right) \left(1-\frac{x}{\pi n}\right)$ over all $n \ne 0$, which is necessary for an absolutely convergent infinite product allowing you rearrange the order of the terms. But then the $n$ and $-n$ terms, for $n>0$, combine together and the exponentials cancel!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of this product for small x's is the product of $(1-x^2/(n \pi)^2)$ which, when you take logs (and due to the second power in x), behaves like the sum over n of $-x^2/(n\pi)^2$, which approaches 0 as x approaches 0.

Comment: This is already very helpful - thank you. Just for clarification: shouldn't it be "1 - sum over n of $-x^2/(n\pi)^2$"? And why are you taking logs? And even if you do the difference between $log(1-x^2)$ and $log(-x^2)$ is not neglectable (esp. not for small x because of $x^2$). Or what am I confusing here? Thank you again!

Comment: And another thing: the value of this product is the product $(1-x^2/(n \pi)^2$ - this holds true *not only* for small x's but for all x, doesn't it? And what I still don't understand is how the $a$ becomes $1$... Thank you again!

Comment: The point is that both `$(\sin x)/x$` and the product approach 1 as `$x\to0$`, and this serves to determine the value of $a$. And the point of the logs is that the theory of infinite products (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) is mostly equivalent to that of infinite series, the correspondence coming from taking logs. Furthermore, `$\log(1+u)\sim u$` for small $u$; apply to `$u=-x^2/(n\pi)^2$`.

Comment: @vonjd: I hope Herald clarified it

Comment: ...although the proper setting is to consider complex x, for which logarithms are considerably more subtle than for real x. I regard taking logs in this case as more of a heuristic method than a rigorous proof (it takes a lot of effort to make it rigorous); the "proper" proof is to develop the theory of infinite products directly, similarly to the theory of infinite sums.

Comment: @Zen if he already knows the factorization up to a multiplicative factor, then no, he does not have to use anything besides very basic real analysis.

Answer (score 18):

The Weierstrass factorization theorem as usually stated tells you only that $a=e^{g(x)}$ for some entire function $g(x)$.  [Hadamard's refinement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Hadamard_Factorization_Theorem) says a little more, based on the growth rate of the function.  In your case, since $\left| \frac{\sin x}{x} \right| < \exp\left(|x|^{1+o(1)} \right)$ as the complex number $x$ grows, Hadamard tells you that $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $1$.  Since $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n^2 \pi^2} \right)$ are both even functions, so is $e^{g(x)}$.  Thus $g(-x)-g(x)$ is a (constant) integer multiple of $2\pi i$.  Hence $g(x)$ is constant, and so is $a$.  Finally, as everyone else has pointed out, taking the limit as $x$ goes to $0$ shows that $a=1$.

See Ahlfors, *Complex analysis* for more about Hadamard's refinement, which relates the "order" and "genus" of an entire function.